# RxJava Login and get User Information

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit

I have 2 functions `loginUser` & `getUserInfomation` use RxJava2 and Retrofit2. After login and get userid, How to I getUserInformation from userId and setText user information for textView?

Thanks. Here is my code:

```
TextView textView;

Maybe<User> loginUser(String username, String password) {
    return RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class)
            .loginUserRx("http://10.0.2.2:3000/users", username, password);
}

Maybe<UserInfo> getUserInformation(String id) {
    return RetrofitClient.getClient().create(RetrofitInterface.class)
            .getUserInfoById("http://10.0.2.2:3000/userinformation", id);
}

loginUser(username, password)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  ...........
```

User.java

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;
@SerializedName("password")
@Expose
private String password;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

UserInfo.java

```
public class UserInfo {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
@SerializedName("address")
@Expose
private String address;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Comment: Call loginuser at first then on Call back success Call again getuserinformation for specific user. Fire your getUserInfo on login method sucess call back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like that

```
loginUser(username, password)
            .flatMap(user -> getUserInformation(user.getId()))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(userInfo ->  { /* TODO set info in textView */ }, error -> { /* TODO handle error */  })
```